# How to get the content://mms-sms/conversations intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Hi I want to know how to specify to a Broadcast Receiver that I want to listen for the content://mms-sms/conversations intent.

In Log cat you can see the Intent fired when you open the messages Application on the emulator or real device. I want to trigger an action when this Intent gets activated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how to specify to a Broadcast Receiver that I want to listen for the content://mms-sms/conversations intent.

That is not possible.

> In Log cat you can see the Intent fired when you open the messages Application on the emulator or real device.

Correct. However, that is starting an activity. You cannot register a `BroadcastReceiver` to find out when the user starts any particular activity.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What I want to do is retrieve the phone number that was clicked inside the message applications, as you can see in the Log cat that information is available when you click a message. Is there any other way to make this?